# Evaluating math problem without order of operations (Python)

Tags: python

I'm trying to find a path in a game, you start out with value = 1 and you're supposed to add/multiply it with the right numbers in order until you get 49. For example,  if I follow the path of  1+2*3, it'll be more like (1+2)*3 = 9 instead of 1+2*3 = 7.

I tried some code, like this:

```
result = 0
while result != 49:
    values = ["+2","+3","+5","*2","*3","*5"]

    pathway = random.sample(values, 5)
    pathway = str(pathway)
    pathway = pathway.replace("', '", "")

    path = "1"+str(pathway)[2:-2]
    result = eval(path)

    print(path, "=", result)
```

I got my result pretty quickly, but when I tried it I realized that this function follows the order of operations (multiplication before addition). Is there an easy way to make it count from left to right without prioritising multiplication?

Comment: If you `eval` a math expression, operation order is implicit **and correct**. If you need to eval the result for every binary expression, then you need to shorten your `values` to a list of two numbers every time.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to simply calculate `1+2*3` (or something) without order of operations, try this:

```
def do_math_left_to_right(expression):
  pieces = []

  i = 0
  for c in expression:
    if c in digits:
      try:
        pieces[i] += c
      except IndexError:
        pieces.append(c)
    elif c in {'+', '-', '*', '/'}:
      i += 1
      pieces.append(c)
  
  last_piece = pieces.pop(0)
  result = 0
  for piece in pieces:
    result = eval(f'{last_piece}{piece}')
    last_piece = str(result)
  return result
```

This is a screenshot of the same function but with debugging messages:
[image: Screenshot]